# Upgrading Custom Extension for PHP 7: How to I instantiate a mysqli data object

Tags: php

I've just upgraded a site from CiviCRM 4.6.38 LTS to CiviCRM 5.7 because we upgraded the server to PHP 7.1.x. As a result 2, custom extensions are warning me because they used mysql_real_escape_string().

PHP 7.1.x doesn't support mysql_real_escape_string() so I need to change to mysqli_real_escape_string() and pass my mysqli data object. The issue I have is that these extensions use the old PHP/MySQL connection as in:

```
$dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($sql);
```

Is there some documentation I can use to quickly get up to speed on updating my code and acquiring a mysqli connection object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CiviCRM has its own database abstraction layer that can handle the escaping for you, so you don't have to use low-level functions like `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You can use it in 2 ways:

1. Parameterize your query like this:

   ```
   CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE id = %1',
     [1 => [$id, 'Integer']]
   );
   ```
2. Escape your variables beforehand with `CRM_Utils_Type::escape()`.

Comment: Thanks Coleman. I'm trying to find the docs on this. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like that documentation is "still to come" https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/

Comment: Have a look at the [CRM_Utils_Type::escape function](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Type.php#L227) to see the possible value types.

Comment: Thanks Coleman. That's really quite useful for what I'm doing.

Comment: I just want to update and confirm that indeed the appropriate method is to escape text strings using CRM_Utils_Type::escape($values['$text_value'], 'String'). Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad that worked. Note that the parameterized query in example 1 also sends the values through that same escape function.